# Reading from ps2 barcode scanner

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to read from a ps2 barcode scanner (Datalogic gryphon D). 
The Arduino is powered by the USB. The circuit is shown below

[image: ps2 connection]

The pinout of the ps2 is
[image: ps2 pinout]
I have used the fritzing pin assignments when making the diagram.

I am using the code from [here](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_PS2Keyboard.html)

```
#include <PS2Keyboard.h>

const int DataPin = 8;
const int IRQpin =  5;

PS2Keyboard keyboard;

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  keyboard.begin(DataPin, IRQpin);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Keyboard Test:");
}

void loop() {
  if (keyboard.available()) {

    // read the next key
    char c = keyboard.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
}
```

The scanner scans and indicates that the scan was successful. The Arduino code shows "Keyboard Test:", but none of the scans show anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pin 5 isn't an IRQ pin, is it? You want pin 2 or 3 for that...

Comment: That article doesn't include those pull-up resistors. PS I doubt you need an added power supply. The maximum current of PS2 (275 mA) is below that of USB. So even adding the few mA that the arduino uses you won't reach the 500mA limit of USB.

Comment: @Majenko I have edited the question. The pins appear to be in the wrong order because I followed fritzing rather than the physical device.

Comment: @Gerben I put in the pull-up resistors because of an article I found (but can't find again). I have removed them now but it still doesn't read. PS  I was connecting through a USB repeater cable and I think it was restricting the current. Getting rid of the repeater allows the scanner to correctly start up, but it is not stable. Most scans fail when it is powered through the Arduino.